# Using cin.eof()

Tags: c++, cin

I have some code and I wanted to use cin.eof() to stop my program from reading the input. I was thinking of doing:

```
char array[10]
while(!cin.eof())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    cin >> array[i];
  }
}
```

And the code goes on. However, when I click '\n', my output is outputted. When i click cntrl + d, (on a UNIX terminal) the program performs the output again and then proceeds to end. How do I get it so that my program stops reading at a newline and prints my output when I type cntrl + d only once?

Thanks.

Comment: break the while loop? how would I do so?

Comment: how would I break out of the for loop?

Comment: *"I wanted to use cin.eof() to stop my program from reading the input"* - [No, you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/743214).

Answer (score 1):

First, `cin.eof()` doesn't do anything useful until input has failed.
You never want to use it at the top of a loop.

Secondly, it's not really clear to me what you are trying to do.
Something like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

perhaps?  This will read a line of text into the variable `line`, until
end of file; when you encounter an end of file, the input will fail, and
you will leave the loop.

Comment: What if I cant use strings? I've already constructed my program with char arrays

Comment: @user1567909 Then you'll have to use the member `istream::getline`, specifying a length, and looping or taking other action if the length is exceeded.  In general, not using `string` for this sort of thing is a guaranteed way of making the code unnecessarily complex and fragile.